# sphinx_automodapi extension - skip a class for class inheritance diagram

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx

I have no MWE since it is really complicated to get one working for this particular problem.
Is there a way to generate the class diagram of a module automatically, but omit one class no to be displayed. I'm using automodapi, an extension of sphinx, but I don't believe it can be done.

Thoughts ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip an object in class inheritance diagram with Sphinx.automodapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187002/skip-an-object-in-class-inheritance-diagram-with-sphinx-automodapi)

Comment: Please do not create a duplicate question to one you asked a few hours ago.